# Calling Stored Procedure using Knime

Tags: knime

I tried calling a stored procedure using DatabaseReader node but it does not worked for me.

Can anyone suggest me how I can call a stored procedure in Knime?

Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: Could you show us how did you tried to call the stored procedure? What database do you use?

Comment: using Database Reader Node, I am using TeraData. In SQL Statement section, i am adding text to call a SP. for e.g Call <DataMart>.TESTSP ('123',121,a)

Comment: Sorry, I have no access to TeraData to check. The code of the Database Reader node suggests stored procedures might work with the Database Reader. Try to call it with a dummy call after it (assuming you do not need the result of the stored procedure), like: `Call <DataMart>.TESTSP ('123',121,a); select * from aTableName`.

Comment: i check in logs actually knime is appending "Select * from (" to SP call.

Comment: Yes, that is why I suggested to add an additional call for a non-stored procedure select. Only the last statement is wrapped with that `select * from (...)`, so the stored procedure might get called before interfering with it.

Comment: i tried that too but its not working. only option i can see is to develop new node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by setting the option "Run SQL Query only during execute, skips configure" on configure dialog. we can execute SP using database reader node.

thanks,
Krishna